# How to clone SVN repository to git by parameters?

Tags: git, svn

I need to clone SVN repository to git.

My SVN repository is very big and I need about 100 revisions back only.

Is there parameters which can help me doing such clone ?

What is the CLI command to clone SVN  repository ?

Answer (score 0):

See docs for [git svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn--rltarggt):

> -r arg
> --revision arg
>
> Used with the fetch command.
>
> This allows revision ranges for partial/cauterized history to be
> supported. $NUMBER, $NUMBER1:$NUMBER2 (numeric ranges), $NUMBER:HEAD, and
> BASE:$NUMBER are all supported.
>
> This can allow you to make partial mirrors when running fetch; but is
> generally not recommended because history will be skipped and lost.

So run

```
git svn init --trunk=trunk_subdir
git fetch -r 100:HEAD # or 100:500 or such
```